# Is it possible to translate websites in Chrome Android in "realtime" like I did on the PC?

Tags: browser, localization

On my Windows 7 computer with Chrome I could translate entire webpages using Google translate with the click of a button.  Is there a way to do this in Chrome or the stock browser? Or any other browser?

OS: 4.1.1 
Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: Have you installed and tried Chrome Beta for Android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en

Comment: I have Chrome installed but how do I access the translation feature?  When I go to a foreign website nothing happens automatically.

Comment: Chrome Beta automatically prompted me when I went to the French version of the BBC site http://bbc.co.uk/french. What site/language are you looking at.

Comment: audible.de for one.

Comment: Just went to audible.de using Chrome BETA version (which is different than Chrome) and it prompted me for translation.

Comment: Is it made by Google?  My phone is not rooted.

Comment: Yes Chrome Beta is made by Google. No rooting is required.

Comment: When I did a Play search some weird "Chrome beta" program showed up.  Net search found it.  How can I give you points since you answered in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chrome Beta for Android. It is made by Google to test out new features. No root is required and can be installed side by side with the original Google Chrome app. By default, Chrome Beta for Android will prompt you for a translation when you visit a site.

The app can be found on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en).

Also, if you use the same Google account on your phone and in your PC browser, you can install the app from your PC without having to search for it on your phone. It will automatically install.

Comment: So the Chrome Beta will always remain a Beta?  Will the translation feature never be put into the stable version?

Comment: That is up to Google when features in Beta will be moved to the main Chrome app. Translation only got added in May 2013 to Beta. But there is probably a good chance that when Google moves the mainline Chrome for Android to version 28, it will get translate.

Comment: Hope the points got to you.

Comment: And main Chrome for Android now has the translation feature: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2013/07/chrome-for-android-update.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with the current beta build of Chrome. It works exactly the same way it does on the desktop.

Comment: How?  On desktop, I used a Google Translate plugin...

Comment: The desktop browser has had a built-it translator for a while now, you can refer to this link for more information: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en.
The Chrome beta for Android also has the same feature, http://cdn.thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/05/chrome_translate_android-730x380.png.

Comment: Can you show me how to activate this feature on Chrome Android?